# Changing values with JS and passing multiple values with POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

Question is defined at the end.

Variables are defined as following: processor = "i5"; grapchard = "2GB"; ram = "8GB"; 
Form HTML is as following:

```
<form action="getdata.php" method="POST" onSubmit="setValue(this)">
<button type="submit" class="button" name='storage' value=''>Click here to send the values</button>
```

The following .JS sets the value to the variable "ram" which is "8GB"

```
function setValue(v) {
  v.storage.value= ram;
  return true;
}
```

The following PHP searches for rows that have "8GB" at column "ram" in the DB

```
<?php
    include_once 'databaseconn.php';

    $ramResult = $_POST['storage'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE ram = '$ramResult' ;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $nameResult = $row['name'];
            $ramResult = $row['ram'];
            $grapchardResult = $row['grapchard']; 
            $processorResult = $row['processor']; 
            $imgResult = $row['img'];        
        }
    }
?>
```

**Question:** what I want is to let .JS set multiple values at the value where the PHP can fetch based on those multiple values, so:

.JS

```
function setValue(v) {
  v.storage.value= ram, processor, graphcard;
  return true;
}
```

And fetch with PHP

```
$allResult = $_POST['storage'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE processor = '$allResult[0]' AND grapchard = '$allResult[1]' AND ram = '$allResult[2]';";
```

Since I'm here, this is obviously not working.. hope someone can help

Comment: Try `v.storrage.value= [ram,processor,graphcard].join(',');` ... then `$allResult = explode(',',$_POST['storrage']);` ... however doing such will need more sanity checks to make sure no one is doing malicious things. Especially with the sql (use prepared statements).

Comment: Thanks! should I use prepared statements for Javascript also or only SQL?

Comment: Also, would i also need to do this if the user is not able to insert nor choose any data?

Comment: @IncredibleHat the code didn't do the trick unfortunately btw